# How to clear the content of a file after it is opened using fstream?

Tags: c++, fstream

I need to open a file in read/write mode, read its content and then clear all. So, I cannot open it in truncate mode. How can I do that?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

#### Hate to disappoint you, but..

There's no standard way of clearing the contents of a file from an open *std::fstream*, the straight forward way is therefore to handle the two operations as what they really are.. *two* operations.

First handle all the reading, and later the writing (through a different *stream object*).

---

#### The solution

In other words; first open the file in *read-only* mode (*std::ifstream*) and read the data you are interested in, then discard that file-handle and open the file again.. this time in *write-only* and *truncation* mode (*std::ofstream*), so that you will clear the contents of the file.

```
std::ifstream ifs ("some_file.txt");

... // read old data

ifs.close ();

std::ofstream ofs ("some_file.txt", std::ios::out | std::ios::trunc); // clear contents

... // write new data

ofs.close ();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just rename the file before reading it and create an empty file with the original name.